# How to ignore the first item in array adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-arrayadapter

```
public class ListViewImgAdapter extends BaseAdapter {                          

    public static final String TAG = "ListViewImgAdapter";                     
    private final int plastic_randomNum = 218947932;                           
    private final int plastic_iconNum = 98367590;                              

    int mGalleryItemBackground;                                                
    private Context mContext;                                                  
    public int pageCount = Broker.model.issueFilter.issueShowingList().size(); 
    public String[] mImageIds;                                                 

    public ListViewImgAdapter(Context c) {                                     
        mContext = c;                                                          
    }                                                                          

    public void updateListSize() {                                             
        pageCount = Broker.model.issueFilter.issueShowingList().size();        
        Log.d(TAG, "RefreshAll, have cells: " + pageCount);                    
    }                                                                          

    public int getCount() {                                                    
        return Broker.model.issueFilter.issueShowingList().size();             
    }                                                                          

    public Object getItem(int position) {                                      
        return position;                                                       
    }                                                                          

    public long getItemId(int position) {                                      
        return position;                                                       
    }                                                                          

    public  View  getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RelativeLayout container ;
//      Log.d(TAG,"GetView. ConvertView "+position+" of "+ Broker.model.issueFilter.issueShowingList().size());
        if (Broker.model.issueFilter.issueShowingList().size()<= position  ) return null;
        if (convertView == null) { 
//          Log.d(TAG,"GetView. ConvertView is null");
            container = new RelativeLayout(mContext);
            IRIssue theIssue = Broker.model.issueFilter.issueShowingList().get(position);   
            final int clickedPosition = position;
```

.............

**Broker.model.issueFilter.issueShowingList().get(position);**

I have a isssueShowingList that is a ArrayList , the problem is how can I ignore the first element in this list in the adapter? I tried return null but it has some error so are there any better way? Thanks

Comment: Please format the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return first element as usual but also set visibility to GONE or set Height to 0 in LayoutParams.

```
if(position==0)
convertView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else
convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

or

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=null;
if(position==0)
lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-1,0);
else
lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-1,-1);

convertView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this , although I set gone it still use the block , that means, the first element is not visible but there is a "white space" at that place

Comment: So try the second solution and set layout height to 0. If not helps, I don't see any other way other that remove first element from adapter

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better option ...

Add a field

```
private List<YOUR_TYPE> mDatas;
 // OR
private ArrayList<YOUR_TYPE> mDatas;
```

Then, in your constructor

```
public ListViewImgAdapter(Context c) {                                     
        mContext = c;                  
        mDatas = Broker.model.issueFilter.issueShowingList();
        if (mDatas > 0)
            mDatas.remove(0);
    }
```

Comment: This is the way I'd do it, then you don't have to code around pretending element 0 doesn't exist.  I think it'll make the code much clearer

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, and far the most proper one, is not to break adapter's logic. It's much better to control data that you pass to the adapter.

So in the code line where you pass data to your adapter, simple remove all rows that the adapter will not need.

```
List<T> myList = fetchMyList();
myList.remove(0);
myList.remove(11);
myList.remove(N);
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.myLayout, myList);
```